# How to get the largest values in SQL?

Tags: sql

For example I want to know who are the tallest guys in some group of people. I use

```
SELECT name, height
FROM people
WHERE height = (SELECT MAX(height) FROM people)
```

But it doesn't look very nice. What is the best way to do it?

Comment: I believe this is the best way you can do it.

Comment: Is there an RDBMS-independent way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use SQL Server then

```
SELECT TOP 1 name, height
FROM people
ORDER BY height DESC
```

SQL Server doesn't support the `LIMIT` method, so here you need to use `TOP`

So if you use MySQL:

```
SELECT name, height
FROM people
ORDER BY height DESC LIMIT 1
```

OR

If you are concerned more than 1 person has the highest height, you can use a sub-query:

```
SELECT name, height
FROM people
WHERE height = (SELECT TOP 1 height FROM people ORDER BY height DESC)
ORDER BY name
```

And of course same example with MySQL:

```
SELECT name, height
FROM people
WHERE height = (SELECT height FROM people ORDER BY height DESC LIMIT 1)
ORDER BY name
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use the `LIMIT` (MySQL) OR `top` (MsSQL):

```
SELECT name, height FROM people ORDER BY height DESC LIMIT 1;

SELECT TOP 1 name, height FROM people ORDER BY height DESC;
```

This will get 1 record.

To get more records, your sub-query works fine. If you don't like sub-queries you can use these queries (MySQL):

```
SELECT MAX(height) INTO @maxHeight FROM person ORDER BY height DESC LIMIT 1;
SELECT * FROM person WHERE height = @maxHeight;
```

This way you can re-use the `@maxHeight` in other queries (for the current connection).

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
  name,
  MAX(height) AS height
FROM people;
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using MySQL:

```
SELECT name, height 
FROM people 
ORDER BY ABS(height) DESC LIMIT 1
```